# How do I get results of several Insert Into Select statements into one row

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have seen a lot of similar questions, but none seem to have an answer applicable to what I am trying to do, so here goes:

I have a table with data spread over 4 rows. Certain values in those rows need to populate another table, all in one row, mapped to specific columns (this to enable a PLC to pick it up).

I created the following query, which as you may expect gives me output in multiples rows (though doesn't actually seem to work when I execute more than 2 part in one go).

How would I go about merging these into the one row? I have had a go with UNION, and had a look at nested queries but can't work it out. Help gratefully received.

```
--////////
--To change format so one row contains all recipe data, 

INSERT INTO dbo.Rep_Criteria (FILE_NAME, BAC, Rev, Tol_Lo1, Tol_Hi1,  Eng_Tol1, Min, Max, Min TCs)
SELECT File_Name, BAC, Rev, Low, High, Eng_Tol, Min, Max,   Min_TC
FROM dbo.Recipe
WHERE ID = 1 ;

INSERT INTO dbo.Rep_Criteria (Tol_Lo2, Tol_Hi2, Eng_Tol2)
SELECT Low, High, Eng_Tol
FROM dbo.Recipe
WHERE ID = 2 ;

INSERT INTO dbo.Rep_Criteria (Tol_Lo3, Tol_Hi3, Eng_Tol3)
SELECT Low, High, Eng_Tol
FROM dbo.Recipe
WHERE ID = 3 ;

INSERT INTO dbo.Rep_Criteria (Tol_Lo4, Tol_Hi4, Eng_Tol4)
SELECT Low, High, Eng_Tol
FROM dbo.Recipe
WHERE ID = 4 ;
--////////
```

This might help, though formatting messed up:

```
Table 1: (Input)
File_Name   BAC Rev Low High    Eng_Tol Min Max Min_TC
Zeppelin    5636    F   0   6   4.0 1550    1725    1
Zeppelin    0   0   6   15  5.0 0   0   0
Zeppelin    0   0   15  100 6.0 0   0   0
Zeppelin    0   0   100 600 15.0    0   0   0
```

```
Table 2: (Output)
File_Name     -      BAC -    Rev -     Tol_Lo1 -       Tol_Lo2 -     Tol_Lo3  -       Tol_Lo4 -        Tol_Hi1 -         Tol_Hi2 -        Tol_Hi3 - -------
Zeppelin             5636    F              0                         6                      15                       100    
 --------  
Tol_Hi4 -        Eng_Tol1 -        Eng_Tol2 -         Eng_Tol3 -         Eng_Tol4  -        Min  -          Max  -          Min# T/C's
600                  4.0                        5.0                        6.0                         15.0                     1550           1725            1
```

Comment: Is the output at the bottom what you want?

Comment: Yes that's right, all in one row, in those columns. Thanks

Comment: Does table 1 have other rows? Perhaps different filenames?  And is there any way to tell which row is lo1 and which is lo2 etc?

Comment: For this step the table will be exactly as in Table 1.   Lo1 will correspond with Low in Row 1 etc.. Just FYI This is part of a massive stored procedure, pulling data from an excel sheet when called by the PLC via a Transaction Manager application. The actual data in Table will vary, depending on which "File_Name is called by the PLC, but that will be out of the scope of this step.

Comment: Milly, Sorry I meant Tol_Lo1 in Table 2 needs to come from Column Low, Row 1 in Table 1 (Table 1 also has an ID Column, numbering the rows)